# Face Model Disappearing When Rendering

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

I'm currently working on my first portrait design and recently all of my renders have been coming out with my main head model completely missing, leaving only the eyeballs and hair particles. Initially, everything was working just fine but when I added a particle system for peach fuzz, that's when the head started disappearing in my renders.

Some more context: the facial textures are pretty hard on my computer so I usually don't add them until I'm ready to do a test render, so maybe whatever is causing this whole thing accidentally happened while I was add those image textures. I'm also using GarageFarm to render everything. [image: Here's a picture of what I'm talking about]

Comment: maybe you've disabled the render option for the emitter in the particle system panel?

Answer (score -1):

Is the face the particle emitter for the hair?

If so, go to the *Particle Settings > Render*. Check if *Show emitter* is checked.